# python POST request issue

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get the title and the link of every article from [this site](https://latercera.com/resultadoBusqueda.html?q=enersis).

The data of interest is loaded with javascript after some time in json response.

```
 var ltcom = 'TEFURVJDRVJB';
 var ltpapaer = 'TFRQQVBFUg==';
 var bender = new Canela.tool.Bender('searchBox',ltcom, {
 replaceImg: 'http://resource.latercera.com/2015/css/img/bx_loader.gif', objectId: 'contentId', hl: 'abstract', taxonomyId: '24', ajaxTpl: true,
 targets: { rowsContainer: 'result', pageContainer: 'pages', resumeContainer: 'resume' },
 parameters: { type: 'CONTENT', fq: 'taxonomyId:24 AND status:2 AND launchDate:[2008-05-31T23:59:59.999Z TO NOW]', sort: 'launchDate desc', rows: 15 },
 templates: {
 rowTpl: '/index/tpl/rowTpl.html',
 rowContainerTpl: '/index/tpl/rowContainerTpl.html',
 pageTpl: '/index/tpl/pageTpl.html',
 pageContainerTpl: '/index/tpl/pageContainerTpl.html',
 resumeTpl: '/index/tpl/resumeTpl.html'
 }
```

I tried using selenium approach, but with no success.

Current code:

```
import requests
url="http://www.latercera.com/app/application"
data= {
    'action':'searchSolr',
    'type':'CONTENT',
    'siteCode':'TEFURVJDRVJB',
    'fq':'taxonomyId:24 AND status:2 AND launchDate:[2008-05-31T23:59:59.999Z TO NOW]',
    'indent':'on',
    'wt':'json',
    'qt':'default',
    'sort':'launchDate desc',
    'start':'0',
    'rows':'15',
    'q':'enersis'
    }
print (requests.get(url, data=data).text)
```

requests.get(url, data=data) spits out 200.

Is there a need to use some header info? How should I move forward with this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If "The data of interest is loaded with javascript after some time in json response", then couldn't you directly get the data from there? I don't know what you're after, but usually if a public website can access it, you can, too. Open Google Chrome developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and navigate to Network tab. You can see all requests and their responses and contents. You can get the URL and params from there. (not an answer because I don't know, if your data is publicly accessible or not. If it helps, I can make it into an answer)

Comment: I am trying to get the title and the link of every article. Take a look here: http://www.latercera.com/resultadoBusqueda.html?q=enersis
'print (requests.post(url, data=data).text)' doesn't return anything also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a *Referer* header:

```
headers = {"Referer": "http://www.latercera.com/resultadoBusqueda.html?q=enersis"}
data = {"type": 'CONTENT', "fq": 'taxonomyId:24 AND status:2 AND launchDate:[2008-05-31T23:59:59.999Z TO NOW]',
        "sort": 'launchDate desc', "rows": 15, "siteCode": 'TEFURVJDRVJB', "q": "enersis",
        "action": "searchSolr"}

r = (requests.post("http://www.latercera.com/app/application", data=data,headers=headers))
print(r)
print(r.content)
```

Which gives you all the data in xml format which we can parse with bs4:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "xml")
print [(s.text, s.parent.select_one("arr[name=url]").text) for s in soup.select("arr[name=n_title]")]
```

That returns:

```
[(u'Las advertencias de la SEC al proceso de fusi\xf3n que Enel impulsa en Enersis', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/09/655-697979-9-las-advertencias-de-la-sec-al-proceso-de-fusion-que-enel-impulsa-en-enersis.shtml'), (u'Enersis Am\xe9ricas aclar\xf3 mejor\xeda en precio de OPA', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/09/655-695035-9-enersis-americas-aclaro-mejoria-en-precio-de-opa.shtml'), (u'Enersis Am\xe9ricas mejora precio de OPA y fija fecha en proceso de fusi\xf3n de activos', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/09/655-694868-9-enersis-americas-mejora-precio-de-opa-y-fija-fecha-en-proceso-de-fusion-de.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/09/653-694868-9-enersis-americas-mejora-precio-de-opa-y-fija-fecha-en-proceso-de-fusion-de.shtml'), (u'Nicola Cotugno, gerente general Enersis Chile: "queremos mantener el liderazgo, #7;pero no s\xf3lo con nueva capacidad"', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/08/655-694297-9-nicola-cotugno-gerente-general-enersis-chile-queremos-mantener-el-liderazgo-pero.shtml'), (u'El buen momento de las firmas chilenas en la bolsa de  EE.UU.', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/08/655-692187-9-el-buen-momento-de-las-firmas-chilenas-en-la-bolsa-de--eeuu.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/08/653-692187-9-el-buen-momento-de-las-firmas-chilenas-en-la-bolsa-de--eeuu.shtml'), (u'Estiman en US$ 145 millones el costo en que incurrir\xe1 Enersis Am\xe9ricas por fusi\xf3n', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/08/655-691649-9-estiman-en-us-145-millones-el-costo-en-que-incurrira-enersis-americas-por-fusion.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/08/653-691649-9-estiman-en-us-145-millones-el-costo-en-que-incurrira-enersis-americas-por-fusion.shtml'), (u'Los pasos que seguir\xe1 el cambio de imagen de Enersis', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/08/655-691378-9-los-pasos-que-seguira-el-cambio-de-imagen-de-enersis.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/08/653-691378-9-los-pasos-que-seguira-el-cambio-de-imagen-de-enersis.shtml'), (u'Enersis, Endesa y Chilectra cambiar\xedan de nombre para unificarse bajo marca Enel', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/08/655-691270-9-enersis-endesa-y-chilectra-cambiarian-de-nombre-para-unificarse-bajo-marca-enel.shtml'), (u'El nuevo dilema de Enel: sepultar #7;las marcas Enersis, Endesa y Chilectra', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/07/655-690896-9-el-nuevo-dilema-de-enel-sepultar-las-marcas-enersis-endesa-y-chilectra.shtml'), (u'SVS niega m\xe1s plazo a Enersis Am\xe9ricas para fusi\xf3n y complica a el\xe9ctrica en EE.UU.', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/07/655-687234-9-svs-niega-mas-plazo-a-enersis-americas-para-fusion-y-complica-a-electrica-en.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/07/653-687234-9-svs-niega-mas-plazo-a-enersis-americas-para-fusion-y-complica-a-electrica-en.shtml'), (u'Rafael Fern\xe1ndez: CMPC #7;tiene un buen compliance y colusi\xf3n fue un "accidente"', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/06/655-685371-9-rafael-fernandez-cmpc-tiene-un-buen-compliance-y-colusion-fue-un-accidente.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/06/653-685371-9-rafael-fernandez-cmpc-tiene-un-buen-compliance-y-colusion-fue-un-accidente.shtml'), (u'The Panama Papers: las sociedades que Mossack Fonseca cre\xf3 para los protagonistas del "Caso Chispas"', u'/noticia/nacional/2016/05/680-679986-9-the-panama-papers-las-sociedades-que-mossack-fonseca-creo-para-los-protagonistas.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/05/653-679986-9-the-panama-papers-las-sociedades-que-mossack-fonseca-creo-para-los-protagonistas.shtml/noticia/despliegue/canal/epigrafe-destacado-rojo/2016/05/3032-679986-9-the-panama-papers-las-sociedades-que-mossack-fonseca-creo-para-los-protagonistas.shtml/noticia/despliegue/home/epigrafe-destacado-rojo/2016/05/3038-679986-9-the-panama-papers-las-sociedades-que-mossack-fonseca-creo-para-los-protagonistas.shtml'), (u'Enersis Am\xe9ricas inicia proceso de fusi\xf3n con Endesa Am\xe9ricas y Chilectra Am\xe9ricas', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/05/655-679596-9-enersis-americas-inicia-proceso-de-fusion-con-endesa-americas-y-chilectra.shtml'), (u'Herman Chadwick Pi\xf1era es elegido como nuevo presidente de Enersis Chile', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/04/655-678650-9-herman-chadwick-pinera-es-elegido-como-nuevo-presidente-de-enersis-chile.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/04/653-678650-9-herman-chadwick-pinera-es-elegido-como-nuevo-presidente-de-enersis-chile.shtml'), (u'Daniel Fern\xe1ndez deja Enersis tras fin de primera etapa en proceso de reestructuraci\xf3n', u'/noticia/negocios/2016/04/655-678440-9-daniel-fernandez-deja-el-cargo-de-country-manager-de-enersis.shtml/noticia/tamano-contenedor/home/col9/2016/04/3057-678440-9-daniel-fernandez-deja-el-cargo-de-country-manager-de-enersis.shtml/noticia/portada/2016/04/653-678440-9-daniel-fernandez-deja-el-cargo-de-country-manager-de-enersis.shtml')]
```